# Sumar precios desde base de datos - React Redux

Tags: base-de-datos, reactjs, react-redux

Estoy intentando armar una tabla de ingresos y gastos para practicar con React, pero me veo perdido al querer sumar todos los precios para poder calcular un Resultado total de las operaciones y mostrarlo en la aplicación.

```
{
  "gastos": [
    {
      "descripcion": "Sellos",
      "precio": "1000",
      "fecha": "2020-11-30",
      "id": 1
    },
    {
      "descripcion": "Telas",
      "precio": "1500",
      "fecha": "2020-11-30",
      "id": 2
    }
  ],
```

Los datos los saco de una base de datos, como la de arriba. Pero al momento de iterar cada precio y tratar de ejecutar la funcion de suma, me devuelve valor de undefined.

```
renderTable = () => {
  
    return this.props.gastos.map((gasto) => {
      const fecha = moment(gasto.fecha).format("DD-MM-yyyy");
     
      
      return (
        <React.Fragment key={gasto.id}>
          <tr>
            <th>{gasto.descripcion}</th>
            <th>$ {gasto.precio}</th>
            <th>{fecha}</th>
            <th className="text-center">
              <a
                href={`/gastos/edit/${gasto.id}`}
                className="btn btn-primary mx-1"
              >
                <i className="fas fa-pen"></i>
              </a>
              <button
                onClick={() => this.props.eliminarGasto(gasto.id)}
                className="btn btn-danger mx-1"
              >
                <i className="fas fa-times-circle"></i>
              </button>
            </th>
          </tr>
        </React.Fragment>
      );
    });
  };

  render() {
  
 
    
    return (
      <div className="col-md-6">
        <h1 className="text-center">Gastos</h1>
        <table
          style={{ width: "100%" }}
          className="table table-striped table-bordered"
        >
          <thead className="thead-dark">
            <tr>
              <th scope="col">Descripcion</th>
              <th scope="col">Precio</th>
              <th scope="col">Fecha</th>
              <th scope="col">Accion</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {this.renderTable()}
            <tr>
              <th>Total Gastos</th>
              <th>total Suma</th>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        <hr />
        <Link to="/gastos/new" className="btn btn-primary">
          Agregar Gasto
        </Link>
      </div>
    );
  }
}



   

     const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
          return {
            gastos: Object.values(state.gastos)
            
            
          };
        };
        
           export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
          listarGastos,
          eliminarGasto,
           `})(Gastos);
```

Estoy utilizando redux, por lo que estoy en duda si tengo que agregar nuevos reductores y acciones o si es posible destructurar la tabla de precios de la base de datos y crear una nueva variable con la suma del total

Comment: Dónde estas realizando la suma?

Answer (score 1):

Lo pude solucionar con la función reduce.. Comparto abajo la solución.

```
renderSuma(){ 
    return this.props.gastos.reduce((acc, curr)=> acc + parseInt(curr.precio), 0)
  }
```